# Why is output not 00706?

Tags: c++, int, cout

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

    int main()
{
    int a = 0706;
    cout<<"Hello"<<a<<endl;
}
```

output:

```
Hello454
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Output is 454 no matter how many zeroes'0' I put before 706

Comment: If you want to pad a number for displaying, you probably want to use [`std::setfill`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) in combination with [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: I think it is indeed a duplicate, but you needed to know the answer to realize that. A bit of a catch 22.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number is octal due to the leading zero.